# Non lazy loading

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

i have a model looks like this.

```
public class TradeModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public BaseProductModel baseProduct { get; set; }

    public string productDescription { get; set; }
    public List<byte[]> images { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    // Date infos
    public DateTime estimatedShippingDate { get; set; }

}
```

What i want to do is. when i call post request i want to send an id of an existing baseProduct not the entire baseProductForm and that being created.

ive tried

```
    [Required]
    public int baseProductId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("baseProductId")]
    public virtual BaseProductModel baseProduct { get; set; }
```

something like this, but seems to be not working.

any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Your model:

```
public class TradeModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int baseProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual BaseProductModel baseProduct { get; set; }

    public string productDescription { get; set; }
    public List<byte[]> images { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    // Date infos
    public DateTime estimatedShippingDate { get; set; }
}
```

Your ViewModel:

```
public class TradeViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int baseProductId { get; set; }

    public string productDescription { get; set; }
    public List<byte[]> images { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    // Date infos
    public DateTime estimatedShippingDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can pass only the baseProductId:

```
public IActionResult(TradeViewModel model)
{
    // Your form will contain only the id anyway so the method below should work.
    // Replace that with your actual context
    //dbcontext.Trades.Add(new TradeModel { ... });
}
```

Comment: I mean i've tried using foreign key and virtual thing but it still would display and require virtual property

Comment: Are you passing the the current model to the View or you created a separated ViewModel?